# All apps crash all the time

Tags: backup, storage, crashes

I have a Sony Xperia U which worked fine. I did not change anything lately.

Today all apps crash on startup. Even *Play Store*, *com.google.process.gapps* and *android.process.acore*. The media gallery seems empty too. Whenever I start something, it crashes, except for opening system settings.

When I connect my phone with my computer the internal storage seems completly empty - so I can't backup anything.

Is there anything I can do to recover my phone and to keep my data like pictures, contacts, ...? *

I tried the save mode, but the erros occur there too.
I tried to boot in Recovery Mode, but all button combinations did not work. I also tried in [USB debugging mode using ADB](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/sony-xperia-u-recovery-mode/), but that did not work too.

<sub>* Since Play Store is not working I can't install any backup tools.</sub>

Comment: Is the device rooted?

Comment: No, sadly it's not.

Comment: OK, that leaves no much options. Still: Try booting into recovery and wiping *CACHE* (only that, not data!). Sometimes things go weird there. Doesn't hurt, no data loss – so you only can win. Or lose some time.

Comment: @Izzy: I tried everthing: Power+VolUp Buttons while booting, Power+VolDown, Power+VolUpDown, kept pressing or pressing multiple times. The phone just boots normal

Comment: (Google-Fu-Ah!) You might wish to use these instructions: [How to Boot Into Sony Xperia U Recovery Mode](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/sony-xperia-u-recovery-mode/). Seems to be a question of timing. Basically, wait until the LED changes its color, then start hammering the volume key.

Comment: @Izzy: I know that link. There is no LED going on or changing color when I boot my Xperia U. Ahhhhh!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, or do you at least know why is this happening?

Comment: No, I resetted the device and get it working again.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into recovery and backup there if you have an option. If not, then wipe it there or with the key combination: Volume Up+Home+Power
Source: www.phonetipsandtricks.com/tips/sony-xperia-u/hard-reset-factory-reset-14/

Comment: I am looking for a way to keep my data and not to reset everything

Comment: deviceguides.vodafone.ie/web/sony-xperia-u/customise/software-update/back-up-phone-memory/ maybe this way?